# keep columns with specific format

Tags: sas

I'd like to keep only columns with specific formatting. For instance, `sashelp.cars` has 2 columns with `DOLLAR` format - `MSRP` & `INVOICE`. I'd like to keep only these two columns. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use dictionary.columns and can do this.

```
 proc sql ;
    select name into :keepcols SEPARATED by " " from dictionary.columns
    where libname = "SASHELP"
     and memname = "CARS"
     and format = "DOLLAR8.";
```

Edit1: You can use format like "DOLLAR%" to find all with dollar formats;

```
  proc sql ;
     select name into :keepcols SEPARATED by " " from dictionary.columns
     where libname = "SASHELP"
    and memname = "CARS"
     and format like "DOLLAR%";



      data cars;
        set sashelp.cars(keep = &keepcols);
     run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Do you know of a quick way to match all DOLLAR formats irrespective of LENGTH?

Comment: Thanks @SanekZhitnik that does it